# Is there a way to seach for columns using the SQL Server Powershell in Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, search, command

I have a larger database with many tables. Now, I would like to search all tables and list those tables that contain a column with the name "column_name". I came across the SQL Server Powershell and am wondering if it can be used to search for columns? If so can you give an example?

Comment: Have a look at the `sys.tables` and `sys.columns` objects, or the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` object. There are plenty of examples out there on how to find out what columns tables have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding on to the answers with a query, below is a general example to execute any `SELECT` query in PowerShell and display the output in a grid.

```
# execute select query and display output in grid
$connectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2012;Integrated Security=SSPI"

$query = @"
SELECT s.name AS SchemaName,
       t.name AS TableName
FROM sys.schemas s
     JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
     JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE c.name = N'column_name';
"@

$command = New-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($query, $connectionString)
$dataTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$dataAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($command)
$dataAdapter.Fill($dataTable)
$dataTable | Out-GridView
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the system objects:

```sql
SELECT s.[name] AS SchemaName,
       t.[name] AS TableName
FROM sys.schemas s
     JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
     JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE c.[name] = N'column_name';
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` view:

```
select table_name, column_name
from information_schema.columns
where c.column_name = ?;
```

These views are actually standardized and available in many databases.